# Comparable means to mimic use of exit in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I'm new to CodeIgniter.  Previously I had developed a login script that would make it so that the login page appeared to be the same page the user was viewing by having lines similar to the following:

```
include('loginpage.php');
exit;
```

But with CodeIgniter the following results in nothing being displayed because the functionality of the output class hasn't been fully executed:

```
$this->load->view('loginpage');
exit;
```

So my question is: Are there any alternative means to mimic the functionality from my previous method?  Ultimately I prefer this approach because it appears to the use that they are on the page they requested only they need to log in first to see it if they haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$msj= $this->load->view('loginpage',$data,true);
exit($msj);
```

Comment: This seems to work... is there anything wrong with using this method?  Does it prevent codeigniter from executing anything important?

Comment: Not bad ... but not for all cases. I use it only in protected controllers.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that in codeigniter is that inside your controller class, you check the login first. That can be done in the constructor:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_checkLogin();
}
function checkLogin()
{
    $loggedIn = $this->getLoggedIn();
    if(!$loggedIn)
    {
        $this->load->view('loginpage');
        exit;
    }
}
```

That function will get executed before any other controller action. If you need this globally within your whole application and you have got multiple controllers, make any of your controllers extend from a base controller that is specific for your application. See *Replacing Core Classes* in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html .

Comment: This is actually the approach I have been trying thus far... view() stores the view in the output class which is output after the rest of the code executes.  I don't want the rest of MY code to execute though its ok for codeigniter to execute its code.